# Sending an array from php to python

Tags: php, python, arrays, json

I am trying to pass an array from php to python, and for some reason when I load the php page I am having trouble so I would much appreciate it if people had suggestions for me to either try a different approach or if people spot a simple error I am missing here because I have been trying to do this for hours now!

Thanks!

PHP:

```
<?PHP
$data = array(1,2,3,4);
$result = sell_exec('python code.py ' . escapeshellarg(json_encode($data)));
$resultData = json_decode($result, true);
var_dump($resultData);
?>
```

Python:

```
import sys
import json
def jsontoarray(json_data):
    data = json.loads(json_data)
    print(json.dumps(data))
jsontoarray(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: What trouble are you having? Please describe the desired behavior and how your code is failing.

Comment: Your example has `sell_exec` instead of `shell_exec`.

Comment: @hcoat woops! That fixed it! You are a lifesaver and are like my favorite person right now! Thank you so much!!