# Sending array from PHP to Python

Tags: php, python, arrays

My PHP file is storing input in the form of an array from HTML checkbox.
I need to pass this array to a python file.
There are few answers already that discuss it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38547656/sending-an-array-from-php-to-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425426/i-have-to-pass-an-array-from-a-php-file-to-python-file-but-my-code-is-giving-out)

They all involve use of JSON as it can serialize data.

However I wanted to know if there is some other way to achieve it, 
for example where I can pass it like integer or string variables like:`$output=shell_exec("python.py $var1 $var2 $arr1);`

If I directly pass the array as above. The data sent is literally `Array`.

So any way to achieve this.

For python , I am reading all arguments as :`arg=sys.argv()
var1 = arg[1]
var2=arg[2]`

Comment: Is there something about the JSON solution you don't like? It will help anyone who answers to know why you don't want to use that solution.

Comment: Yes, I am passing other variables directly through the command line. I want to maintain a consistent way of passing data rather than use different methods for different data structures