# how to send an array of URI's from php to python and print it there

Tags: php, python, arrays

I am trying to send array of URI's from my php to my python scraper. the array contains links to scrape.

I got example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38547656/sending-an-array-from-php-to-python), and it worked fine with sending array of integer, but when I try to fill the array using URI's, error showed up.

php snippet:

```
$array = ["https://www.google.com/","https://www.google.com/","https://www.google.com/"];
//$array = [1,2,3]; // This is worked fine
$resultScript= system('python C:\xampp\htdocs\selenium\dummy.py '   .escapeshellarg(json_encode($array)));
$resultData = json_decode($resultScript, true);
var_dump($resultData);
```

python :

```
import sys
import json
def jsontoarray(json_data):
    data = json.loads(json_data)
    print(json.dumps(data))
jsontoarray(sys.argv[1])
print(data)
```

result from my IDE

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\selenium\dummy.py", line 8, in <module>
    jsontoarray(sys.argv[1])
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\selenium\dummy.py", line 6, in jsontoarray
    data = json.loads(json_data)
  File "C:\Users\PC2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\PC2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\PC2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
NULL

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: look what gets in print(sys.argv[1])

Comment: the print result was : [ https:\/\/www.google.com\/ , https:\/\/www.google.com\/ , https:\/\/www.google.com\/ ]

Comment: you gets list and should str. First value in list jsontoarray(sys.argv[1][0])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18460958/2604320), reason of getting error like:

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 3 (char 2)

can be:

- non-JSON conforming quoting
- XML/HTML output (that is, a string starting with <), or
- incompatible character encoding

So based what you have I would bet that there is encoding problem.

- Take a look on your PHP file and make sure it's UTF-8 encoded.
- Check Python script file encoding and it would be good if you add at the beginning of the file line below to enforce proper encoding.

  `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

so your python file will look like:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import json
def jsontoarray(json_data):
    data = json.loads(json_data)
    print(json.dumps(data))
jsontoarray(sys.argv[1])
```

additionally for debuging you could print type of `sys.argv[1]`:

```
print(type(sys.argv[1]))
```

you should get `string` or `bytes` (for UTF-8) string. If you got something else you could convert it into string like:

```
str(sys.argv[1])
```